# Mediated envy-free and efficient cake cutting with n=2?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, fair-division

Is there an algorithm in literature to compute an efficient (pareto optimal) and envy-free cake cutting when there are only $n=2$ players and a mediator?

Comment: Will Mediator work for free?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "Mediator" - what  exactly is his job? In any case, you may find some information on PEEF (Pareto-Efficient-Envy-Free) division here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficient_cake-cutting#PEEF_division_-_general_cakes

Comment: I don't know about the mediator, but I assume you know about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brams%E2%80%93Taylor_procedure

Answer (score 6):

Huh? I cut, you choose. Why do we need a Mediator?

Comment: I suspect that "envy-free" might rule this out, though I don't know what assumptions are going into this, or what "envy-free" means in a technical sense.  Perhaps if I'm bad at cutting, then I will envy you for getting the bigger piece?

The use of an undefined technical term like this from economics makes the question sound like a homework question.

Comment: >Perhaps if I'm bad at cutting, then I will envy you for getting the bigger piece?

And what if you're bad at choosing? Then it's hopeless! I think your objection is silly.


Comment: That didn't work very well :-(  
I meant to quote Kenny, and add further commentary,but comments don't parse like answers do...

Comment: Cut and choose is not pareto optimal, which is: there could be a better assignment that makes some of the players better off without making anybody worse off. This is the case, because in the cut and choose method, the person that cuts is guaranteed to have 1/2 of it view of the cake, whereas the person the chooses get *at least* one half.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me, whatever '1/2 of it view of the cake' means. Any improvement for the cutter is necessarily worse for the chooser. So why isn't it Pareto optimal? On an unrelated note, if the cutter can't be trusted to look after their own interests, we don't seem to have anything to go on at all! (And in the real world, of course, 'envy-free' is an impossible goal...)

Comment: @TonyK:  Suppose each player assigns a different measure to the cake, and player $i$ seeks to maximize $\mu_i(A_i)$, where $\mu_i$ is that player's measure and $A_i$ is the piece that player ends up with.  Then it is certainly not true that any improvement for the cutter must be worse for the chooser.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:

http://ideas.repec.org/p/pad/wpaper/0022.html

or the description of Crawford Divide and Choose as described in the book Equity: In Theory and Practice, by H. Peyton Young, Princeton U. Press.